# Multiple ViewComponents in Razor makes page load slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Within a legacy mvc project view , there are multiple ViewComponents and the end result is the page rendering is very slow

```
  @await Component.InvokeAsync("GetRelatedItems", new { ID = Model.A_ID, BID =  Model.B_ID })
     @await Component.InvokeAsync("GetRelatedItems1", new { ID = Model.A_ID, BID =  Model.B_ID })
     @await Component.InvokeAsync("GetRelatedItems2", new { ID = Model.A_ID, BID =  Model.B_ID })
```

Similar to this there are around 5-6 ViewComponents and is there any way to improve the load speed of the page ? I do not need to wait for the completion of ViewComponent execution to proceed with rendering of next one.

Does the current implementation is sufficient ?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ViewComponents won't makes your page slow **unless** there is an issue in one of your ViewComponents.(for example fetching from the database that you can use MiniProfiler to detect, or razor/HTML issue)

The easiest way is to comment or remove @await Component.InvokeAsync ... in your razor page one by one and test page load to detect which one Couse this problem.